Dynamically load in an image into anylogic
I'm making an anylogic model, in which by a button, I want to load in an image from the local computer which runs the simulation or at the end even the stand alone application should be able to load in an image. Than I want to set this image to the background of my model.
I already tried a lot but nothing seems to work? the complexity lays in the fact that the image is not imported at model start up, but during run-time, so does anyone know how to fix this?
I tried everything as image.add('filename') and switch indexes but nothing seems to work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Load the image at design time via the "Image" block but set its "visible" property to false.
At runtime in your button, simply call myImage.setVisible(true)
If your clients need to change images, you can:

simply replace the image in the model folder. Ensure to use the same name
or you prepopulate the image with all potential candidates and use the myImage.setIndex(...) method to change which is displayed


Hi Benjamin, thanks for the response, the problem lays in the fact that I want the user of the model to change the image sometimes. So it is not always the same image, and I want the user of my model to upload the image by themselves (if this is possible ofcourse)

see edited response. pls upvote if it was helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Hi benjamin, thanks again, sorry I think I did not provide enough context, the image is a lay-out of a potential factory in an image, the user of the model can than drag and drop in agents at certain locations to easily withouth knowing anything about anylogic create a factory in simulation. However this floor lay-out is so constantly changing and there are not 10 options, but it really depends on the user. Putting it in the same folder could work, however than it can not be used as stand alone application, since than you really need the .alp file etc.

no other way afaik. You cannot drag in stuff into compiled models. But if it is standalone, users cannot drag in stuff... Not sure I understand the usecase

Oke thankyou, than I should think about other solutions or indeed just change the image in the folder.
